# Retrieve latest modified zip files with Spring Integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I've written an application that downloads files from a Sftp server. What I want to achieve is to download only ZIP files, but to download them only when they've been modified.

I've written a `SftpInboundFileSynchronizer` and several `InboundChannelAdapter`. What is weird is that the same file gets downloaded once and again. I know the key is to choose the right filters, but I don't know how to accomplish it.

```
public static final String SYNCHRONIZER_BEAN_NAME = "synchorinzer-bean-name";
    @Bean(SYNCHRONIZER_BEAN_NAME)
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer(
            SessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> sf,
            PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore ms,
            AppProps cfg) {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sync = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sf);
        sync.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        sync.setRemoteDirectory(cfg.getFtpRemoteDirectory());
        sync.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
        // sync.setFilter(); ????
        return sync;
    }


    public static final String GIPUZKOANA_OUT_CHANNEL_NAME = "GIPUZKOANA_OUT_CHANNEL";
    public static final String GIPUZKOANA_SYNCHRONIZER_BEAN_NAME = "GIPUZKOANA_FILE_SYNCHRONIZER_BEAN";
    @Bean(GIPUZKOANA_SYNCHRONIZER_BEAN_NAME)
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = GIPUZKOANA_OUT_CHANNEL_NAME)
    public MessageSource<File> gipuzkoanaMessageSource(
            @Qualifier(SYNCHRONIZER_BEAN_NAME) SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sync,
            AppProps cfg) {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sync);
        source.setLocalDirectory(cfg.getGtfsLocalDirSyncGtfs());
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setMaxFetchSize(1);
        source.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(files -> Lists.newArrayList(files)
                .stream()
                .filter(f -> f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(cfg.getGtfsGipuzkoana()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return source;
    }
    // ...
```

I've tried so far `new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(ms, "gtfs_")`, `new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.zip")`... but with no luck.

How can achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like this:

```
    ChainFileListFilter<SftpClient.DirEntry> chainFileListFilter =
            new ChainFileListFilter<>()
                    .addFilters(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.zip"),
                            new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(ms, "gtfs_"));
    sync.setFilter();
```

This way it will check for file extension first and only then check for its previous state after processing.

Not sure about your "only when they've been modified" since this filter cannot know about such a state. You can try with a `LastModifiedFileListFilter` modification for SFTP to be sure that the file is old enough to be pulled.

Comment: With "only when they've been modified" I mean that I want the `@ServiceActivator` to be run only when a new ZIP file. Imagine I've got `A.zip` and `B.zip` files. Having into account that I've got 1 inbound synchronizer and N inbound file synchronizing message sources (1 per file) and N service activator, I'd want the service activator to be run when the ZIP file is new. So far, it gets run once and again.

Comment: To clarify.. What I want is that I only want ZIP files to be synchronized when their modify time gets updated (new file or updated).

Comment: OK. So, your point is exactly what an `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` does: it picks new and modified files. If file has been already processed without changes, it is not polled again. Unless your `MetadataStore` is not persistent and does not hold the state between application runs. Therefor my answer is for you.